# custom plugin with upload files does not work

Tags: php, plugin-development, uploads

I an creating a custom plugin that used shortcodes.. then it will have a feature that will upload files and stores it in `wp-content/uploads/` directory.. but it seems I got an error..

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://mysitecom/wp-content/uploads/myfiles/1991117- DriverLiscence.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/user/public_html/mysite/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/functions.php on line 1266

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpOOkdNJ' to 'http://mysitecom/wp-content/uploads/myfiles/1991117-DriverLiscence.jpg' in /home/user/public_html/mysite/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/functions.php on line 1266
```

this is the code:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$wp_upload_url =$upload_dir['baseurl']; 
$uploaddir = $wp_upload_url."/myfiles/";

$temp = explode(".",$_FILES[$file_uploaded]["name"]);
$newfilename = $contactID. '-'. $type . '.' .end($temp);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newfilename;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_uploaded]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo 'success';
}
```

ny question is that, how can I get the exact path of the `/wp-content/uploads/myfiles/` so that I can upload files?

Answer (score 1):

Use Wordpress defult media uploader and get uploaded link in jquery response it is quit easy

```
<label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>

<?php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: true
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            console.log(custom_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON());
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move a file over HTTP, instead you need to move it using local path.

```
(e.g. /home/content/site/folders/filename.php).
```

normally people upload files to media library. The following code shows how to upload a file from a plugin.

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        }
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, 0 );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi grandcoder, thanks for the reply.. base on your code where should the files will be uploaded? or what directory?

Comment: https://tommcfarlin.com/upload-files-in-wordpress/ may help you